# Add CSS in Pipe Angular2

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-pipe

Is it possible to add css in pipe? If not, can you suggest what is the workaround for this scenario?
What I want is when backend returns negative values, it will  be displayed as red without the negative sign, otherwise display normal (black text)

```
<td class="text-right">
    {{ value | myCustomPipe}}
</td>
```

My pipe file:

```
export class myCustomPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, ...args: any[]): string {
    if (+value < 0) {
      return (Math.abs(+value)).toFixed(2);  // possible to add css in here?
    } else if (+value === 0){
      return '-';
    } else {
      return (+value).toFixed(2);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Pipes are for transforming values, not creating HTML/CSS. Just style the number as usual with something like `[class.negative]="value < 0"`.

Comment: use the pipe in the style="color: {{ value | aPipeThatReturnsTheColor}}"

Comment: @torazaburo i see. i thought pipe can handle css/stylings. i find your statement "Pipes are for transforming values" strong. thank you so much! :D

Comment: @Milad ill try that sample code of yours. thank you for the input guys!